# Extending classes with package level access

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus, uimanager

Java 1.6 have Synth plaf classes with package level access.

I try to extend these

`package javax.swing.plaf.synth;`

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;

class MyCheckBoxUI extends SynthCheckBoxUI {
    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent b) {
        return new MyCheckBoxUI();
    }
}
```

However while instantion, this fails with

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class javax.swing.plaf.synth.MyCheckBoxUI cannot access its superclass javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthCheckBoxUI

```
public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());

                break;
            }
        }

        UIManager.put("CheckBoxUI", "javax.swing.plaf.synth.MyCheckBoxUI");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.add(new JCheckBox("Hello", true));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Could anyone suggest how can I get around this situation. I have to stick to jdk 1.6